# Обработка пакетов данных из интернета с помощью Java

Tags: java, tcp, udp, трафик

Хочу разобраться в следующем вопросе.

**Задача следующая:** по сети Wi-Fi, либо через подключенный кабель, или же мобильный интернет (без разницы), нам приходит пакет данных на сетевую карту (верно?). Тобишь изначально данные приходят на физический уровень и затем они "обрабатываются" (кодируются/декодируются) и идут вверх по ступенькам сетевой модели ОСИ. И в самом верху у нас есть уровень представления (который и занимается кодированием/декодированием данных в удобный вид для сети/приложения) и прикладной уровень. Есть ли возможность самостоятельно разбирать пакеты данных, приходящие уже на уровень представления (будь то от приложения или же из сети ответ на запрос) и самому решать, что с ними делать? Интересуют способы посредством языка Java.

**Суть**: Обработка входящих и исходящих пакетов данных через сеть посредством Java.

Так же буду очень благодарен за наводящие ссылки. Что почитать по этому вопросу, куда обратиться?

**UPD:** Реализовать перехват трафика от приложения.

Comment: Читайте про [сокеты](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/package-frame.html) и [каналы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да, спасибо. С этим плюс-минус знаком. Хотелось бы немного конкретнее, чем и как я могу разобрать нужные мне пакеты. Как понять, что, предположим, пакет с звуковой дорожкой, который пришел хрому, пришел именно на такой то порт.

Comment: Вы хотите перехватывать трафик других приложений?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Вот именно эти пару слов я так долго формулировал в вопросе. Да, думаю это то, что я хотел бы осуществить.

Comment: Вы не сможете сделать этого на Java. Разве что написать прокси-сервер и настроить тот же Хром на его использование.

Comment: Скажем так, создать определенный фильтр между прикладным и уровнем представления, который мог бы смотреть данные, которые проходят и если что, не пропускать их. Либо вообще изменять, если это необходимо. Это возможно?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, думаю, мне любые варианты подойдут. Не побрезгую и прокси-сервером, если он позволит мне осуществить задуманное.